# CodeIgniter. Adding my own library, getting "Undefined property" error

Tags: php, codeigniter, controllers

I am trying to add this code https://gist.github.com/farico/3938084 which is making declension of nouns to my CI script and I get this:

> Message: Undefined property: Linksniavimas::$sau
>
> Filename: libraries/Linksniavimas.php
>
> Line Number: 117

Line 117:

```
foreach ( $this->$linksnis as $from=>$to ) {
```

Also, this error:

> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: libraries/Linksniavimas.php
>
> Line Number: 117

Beginning of Linksniavimas.php file looks like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Linksniavimas {
public function linksniuoti() {
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8') ;
```

And loading this library in controller file:

```
$this->load->library('linksniavimas');
echo $this->linksniavimas->getName('Jonas Petraitis');
```

What could cause this error? Also, sorry for my English.

Comment: Is there a typo on line 117 so that it should read `foreach ( $this->linksnis as $from=>$to ) {` (removed a `$`)?

Comment: No, it isn't. That code from github singly works perfectly.

Comment: Did you remove the test code from the very bottom of Linksniavimas?

Comment: Yes. Also, I tried both the way from example and that I wrote in question post to use this code from controller.

Comment: on line 117 -- try putting brackets around $linksnis: 
foreach ( $this->{$linksnis} as $from => $to )

Comment: @cartalot still no effect.

Comment: ok i installed the code in CI and tested with the example code you have and i can confirm it worked without error. maybe when you copy / pasted the Linksniavimas code you got a stray invisible character?